# How to access object value with ( ) parentheses in name?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an object that I have filled from data in a CSV file.

One of my ids is called "Disk_Usage(MB)"

I try using my object.Disk_Usage(MB) but receive an error because javascript thinks disk usage is a function and that MB is a variable.

I receive a reference error on the console saying MB is not defined.

Comment: Use bracket notation with a string literal.

Comment: See [*JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets/4968448#4968448).

Comment: Sounds like you haven't read your JavaScript book yet. Why not?

Comment: See [ECMAScript 5.1 Section 11.2.1 Property Accessors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)

Answer (score 6):

Use array/bracket notation:

```
var propertyValue = yourObject['Disk_Usage(MB)'];
```

If you're wondering why you need to do this and/or "but my object isn't an array!," I would suggest having a read through the "[Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)" article over at MDN.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
object['Disk_Usage(MB)']
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Answer (score 0):

Although [object member access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) *can* be performed like this:

```
var o = { 'abc': 123 };
console.log(o.abc);
```

it is often more convenient to use array-bracket notation:

```
console.log(o['abc']);
```

This is one of those times when you *must* do so, since your key has characters in it that make it an illegal identifier. You *must* provide it as a string.

Personally, as a matter of consistency, I try to stick to the array-bracket notation all the time.

- Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties